# Using macro Concatenation of Multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

please anybody help in concatenating cells using Excel 2007 macro. I have columns A to E. I want to concatenate all the Columns in column F. Please note that I don't know the exact number of rows in the all the Columns, but macro should stop concatenating when there are no values in the said columns. Sample:

```
A       B           C          D     E           F
O      ABC         DEF        GHI    E       OABCDEFGHIE

O      JKL         MNO        PQR    E       OJKLMNOPQRE

O      STU                   VWXYZ   E       OVWXYZE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exel - Concatenate many columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628511/exel-concatenate-many-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try with the following code:

```
Sub concat()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To 1
If (Cells(i, j).Value <> "") And (Cells(i, j + 1).Value <> "") And (Cells(i, j + 2).Value <> "") Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = Cells(i, j).Value + Cells(i, j + 1).Value + Cells(i, j + 2).Value
Else
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = "Empty cell found"
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

It may look long but i hope you ll get some idea...

Comment: I would use the same logic with one change... I'

Comment: I would use the same logic... But I'll prefer to copy the range into an array and get better performence

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use excel formula **CONCATENATE**, check the below line:

Use this formula in column F **=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)**

Answer (score 0):

Set a column to put the formula which is in next to the most significant cell. .

> =Concatenate($A1:$somecell1)

Here you *need not to* worry about the exact cell nums.