# VBA passing range of cells into function

Tags: vba, excel

Let me start off by saying I have been using VBA for about 2 hours.
  I am a Java guy, I know nothing about VBA.

What I want is to write an Excel function that will take a **range of cells** and a **delimiter** as parameters, and then return a concatenation of those cells with the specified delimiter.

example
concatenateRange(B1:D1, ";") would return the equivilent of =B1&";"&C1&";"&D1

Here is my code (which does not work)

```
Function concatenateRange(rng As Range, delimiter As String)

    str = ""
    For Each cell In rng
        str = str & delimiter & cell
    Next

    concatenateRange = str

End Function
```

The error I get when I try to use the above function is "Argument not optional"

Comment: @johnzilla already provided an answer and I agree *Str* is a built in *VBA Function* but you can [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628511/exel-concatenate-many-columns/25635231#25635231) as well. This proposes various ways of getting what you want done.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined variable Str over a built in VBA function Str(). VBA does not like this.

this works fine:

```
Public Function concatenateRange(rng As Range, delimiter As String)

    Str1 = ""
    For Each cell In rng
        Str1 = Str1 & delimiter & cell
    Next

    concatenateRange = Str1

End Function
```

Comment: But you wil get an extra delimiter at the start